# When to average samples in order to avoid pseudoreplication?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, mean, mixed-model

My question is when to average samples or when it is allowed to apply a mixed effects model.

I have the following constellation:
there is a cell-line experiment conducted in a 96-wellplate, meaning that we have cell material from the same source but incubate samples in 96 individual wells on one large plate (the 96-wellplate). This plate is repeated every day for seven days, so we have for each day 96 wells of each plate thus n=672 observations. On every plate, there are 12 treatments (including 4 controls), which are repeated 8 times.

Since for every day the preparation of treatments were mixed again. I ask now whether the 8 observations per treatment per day need to be averaged, so I end up with only 7 observations per treatment or if I can use mixed effect modelling and use day as a random factor.

In literature I found all possible combinations of averaging only, averaging and applying mixed effect models and also only mixed effect models...

the data is "mainly" normal distributed  (one treatment is a bit variable...) hence no need for glmms .